# React-Router active class is not working for nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, jsx

I've looked at several github issues and similar posts, and I can't figure this out. I have here my routes:

```js
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Landing} />
      <Route path='login' component={LoginContainer} />
      <Route path='user' component={UserContainer} onEnter={checkAuth} >
        <Route path='home' component={HomeContainer} />
        <Route path='settings' component={SettingsContainer} />
        <Route path='doc_attributes' component={AttributesContainer} />
        <Route path='groups' component={GroupsContainer} />
        <Route path='rules' component={RulesContainer} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/dropbox/auth_finish' onEnter={doDropbox} />
      <Route path='/box/auth_finish' onEnter={doBox} />
      <Route path='/googledrive/auth_finish' onEnter={doGDrive} />
      <Route path='/onedrive/auth_finish' onEnter={doOneDrive} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Here are the links of interest:

```js
<li><Link to='/user/home' activeClassName="activeLink"><i className="fa fa-home fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link></li>
<li><Link to='/user/settings' activeClassName="activeLink"><i className="fa fa-wrench fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link></li>
<li><Link to='/user/groups' activeClassName="activeLink"><i className="fa fa-users fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link></li>
<li><Link to='/user/rules' activeClassName="activeLink"><i className="fa fa-tasks fa-3x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link></li>
```

The links load just fine, but they never get the active class CSS. Only the first route on load gets it and nothing else. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: By first route you mean `/user/home` or `'/'`?

Comment: /user/home, or whichever route is in the url when I refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's been a while since this question was asked, but I figured out the answer so I should share it.

In my container which renders the component and receives the state updates for the navigation, I needed to put `{pure: false}` in the connect function. Essentially it has to do with the fact that if your component isn't "pure" (updates only comes from props) then it relies on react context to re-render. Here is the block of code:

`const NavContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
    MapStateToProps,
    MapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    {pure: false}
)(Nav)`

Documentation for the issue: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

The issue which helped me solve it: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3286

Comment: Thank you. Was about to post the same question when I stumbled upon yours.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of onEnter you could use `componetDidMount`

The bright side here is that you can also use it with `componentWillUnmount` in order to remove timers for example or to clear cache.

I hope this helps, here's some extra info on this subject :) 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

Comment: Is it related to this question?

Comment: yes, instead of using activeClass which he mention that has problems, he can use directly componentDidMount() method in each component and he will know exactly what loaded from where, plus the option to unmount any code that he has enabled.

Comment: But the problem is, onEnter should have absolutely no impact on the activeClass declaration.

Comment: it shouldn't,but i'm assuming you are having an issue similar to https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1996 . Which is why I think you have a better option to work directly with reactjs basic components to do your work. Still, this was just a suggestion, maybe a more experimented developer would come with a better solution to the problem.